# SSRS - Counting Correct Answers and Calculating Percentages via Comparison Fails

Tags: reporting-services

This is my first time using SSRS, so be gentle! I'm working on a report where I want to compare the number of correct answers to the number of all user answers for a group. The group repeats and looks set up okay, so that part isn't a worry. It's the calculation of a field that seems to be the worry.

Here's my dataset:

```
    TopicID TopicName   GroupScore  TotalPossible   QuestionID  Question                       CorrectAnswer    GroupAnswerScore    UserAnswer
    1       Test Topic  2            1               6          When did it start?              1917            1                   1896
    1       Test Topic               1               3053       Who was the 1200th governor?    Olestra Chyppin 1                   Brent Spoon
    1       Test Topic  2            1               3053       Who was the 1200th governor?    Olestra Chyppin 1                   Olestra Chyppin
```

This query to calculate percentage based on correct answers compared to all answers does not work:

```
=IIF(Fields!UserAnswer.Value=Fields!CorrectAnswer.Value,1,0)/COUNT(Fields!UserAnswer.Value))
```

Likewise, this query to simply find the number of correct answers doesn't work:

```
=IIF(Fields!UserAnswer.Value=Fields!CorrectAnswer.Value,1,0)
```

Both return either zero (if I reverse the order on the percentage portion) or "infinity". I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the aggregate of your data set.  In this case you would use  `SUM`.  Your statement evaluates a single row and it is unclear which row. The statement to find the total number of correct answers would be

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!UserAnswer.Value=Fields!CorrectAnswer.Value,1,0))
```

You may need to include a scope if you have groupings in your report.  See the SSRS documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Aggregates) for more information.